# Insert data into bucketed Hive table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, insert, sql-insert

Advice on creating/inserting data into Hive's bucketed tables.

Did some reading (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables) and tested few options but with no success.

Currently I get following error while running insert:

`Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask`

Create code:

```
CREATE test_in (
id VARCHAR(250), 
field_1 VARCHAR(250), 
field_2 VARCHAR(250), 
field_3 VARCHAR(250),
field_4 VARCHAR(250), 
field_5 VARCHAR(250)
)
PARTITIONED BY(ds STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(id) into 10 buckets
STORED AS orc
tblproperties("orc.compress"="NONE","transactional"="true");
```

Insert code:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test_in
VALUES (
'9gD0xQxOYS',
'ZhQbTjUGLhz8KuQ',
'SmszyJHEqIVAeK8gAFVx',
'RvbRdU7ia1AMHhaXd9tOgLEzi',
'a010E000004uJt8QAE',
'yh6phK4ZG7W4JaOdoOhDJXNJgmcoZU'
)
```

Need help in creating proper syntax for create/insert statement and some explanation on bucketting in Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CREATE STATEMENT - The word `table` is missing. (May be a typo)
2. INSERT STATEMENT - Partition details are missing. Partition value is required during INSERT operation since it is a partitioned table.

The correct and working queries are below,

**CREATE STATEMENT:**

```
CREATE TABLE test_in (
id VARCHAR(250), 
field_1 VARCHAR(250), 
field_2 VARCHAR(250), 
field_3 VARCHAR(250),
field_4 VARCHAR(250), 
field_5 VARCHAR(250)
)
PARTITIONED BY(ds STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(id) into 10 buckets
STORED AS orc
```

**INSERT STATEMENT:**

```
INSERT INTO test_in
PARTITION (ds='123')
VALUES (
'9gD0xQxOYS',
'ZhQbTjUGLhz8KuQ',
'SmszyJHEqIVAeK8gAFVx',
'RvbRdU7ia1AMHhaXd9tOgLEzi',
'a010E000004uJt8QAE',
'yh6phK4ZG7W4JaOdoOhDJXNJgmcoZU'
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why `ds = 123`?

Comment: I just used a random value for the partitioned column `ds` for the query to work. You can use the value as per your requirement.

Comment: Do have maybe some documentation on logic behind this syntax?

Comment: This might help -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert

Comment: Even more helpful - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this statement if we want to add to copy values from an unpartitioned table and store it in the new partitioned one like this.

```
INSERT INTO test_in
PARTITION(ds="some_value")
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 Second_table;
```